# how to view people with more than 2 subjects when using 2 different id's on mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to view all students that take more than two classes by using the `student.id`, (`student.id` is unique but can have many `class.id` associated with it).
If `student.id` has more than two classes associated with it, I need to display this data, using MySQL.

Comment: Show your schema.

Comment: Please show which you want into the result.

Answer (score 0):

Without any data provided, and limited to just `student.id` and `class.id` columns, you can try this query:

```
SELECT student.id,COUNT(class.id) as "Total Class" FROM your_table GROUP BY student.id;
```